# Network Game - Interpolation/extrapolation with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, networking, interpolation, sprite-kit

I'm currently facing a - I think - very common networking problem. But I can't find an answer with SpriteKit.

Let's take a simulation with a ball that bounce again wall. The objective is to synch the ball position on two devices via bluetooth or Wifi.

- It uses `SpriteKit` physics to simulate ball movement and collisions
- It uses `MultipeerConnectivity` for networking on bluetooth or Wifi.
- The Device A - master - simulates everything and tells ball position and vector to Device B at synchronisation points. The Device B simulates the scene between synch points.

Currently, the ball in Device B is always ~50ms later than device A. To prevent this, someone told me about "interpolation" : Device B receive the DeviceA's ball position and knows the info is 50ms old. So Device B should be able to predict the "real" position 50ms after the received one.

But I did not find a way to do this with SpriteKit. I don't want to manually develop what's SpriteKit physics automatically made for me!
I'm just searching for a way to simulate a 50ms jump in the future!

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with [`speed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/speed) property of your `SKScene`. It can set above `1.0`.